# Cloud Variable X1 and X2 not updating

Tags: mit-scratch

I can't get X1 and X2 to update

```
When Green Flag Clicked
Forever
   if localplayer == 1
      (Cloud)Dir1 = direction
      (Cloud)X1 = X position
      (Cloud)Y1 = Y position
   else
      if localplayer == 2
         (Cloud)Dir2 = direction
         (Cloud)X2 = X position
         (Cloud)Y2 = Y position
```

I have the following cloud variables:
P1
P2
Dir1
Dir2
X1
X2
Y1
Y2
HP1
HP2

They all work, except X1 And X2, which refuse to update

Localplayer is working, and the variable updates locally, but not on the cloud data

Here's the project

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/739146137/

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are setting multiple cloud variables at once, it is bad practice. cloud variables in scratch only update one variable every 0.1 seconds. this means if you have three variables all linked to one player, every cycle it will update the variable that changes the most.

i would recomend following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNv9iehpGRQ)

Comment: Thanks so much, I never imagined this would be a thing, thill will help so much in my game